# How is Ruby /lib/time.rb thread-safe?

Tags: ruby, datetime, thread-safety, global-variables, standard-library

While looking at RSS stdlib monkey patching the Time classes, I've found that global variables `$1` `$2` `$3` ... are heavily used there. Alright, I can live without making several RSS feeds at the same time.

But I've found the same horror here:
- /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0//time.rb
And here:
- https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c8b3f1b470e343e7408ab5883f046b1056d94ccc/lib/time.rb

How does Ruby `/lib/time.rb` work without thread errors?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1`, `$2`, etc. are special global variables that hold regular expression match results and are internally a [thread-local variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage), and hence, *code using them are thread-safe*.

Here is an excerpt from [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html),

> #### Special global variables
>
> Pattern matching sets some global variables :
>
> - $~ is equivalent to ::last_match;
> - $& contains the complete matched text;
> - $` contains string before match;
> - $' contains string after match;
> - **$1, $2 and so on contain text matching first, second, etc capture group;**
> - $+ contains last capture group.
>
> ***These global variables are thread-local and method-local variables.***

Example below:

```
Thread.new {
  "A B C".match(/(\w)/)
  p $1 # Prints "A"

  Thread.new {
    "X Y Z".match(/(\w)/)
    p $1  # Prints X
  }.join

  p $1 # Prints "A", shows that $1 was not corrupted by inner thread

}.join
```